# Writing to a file without overwriting or appending

Tags: java, file, append, overwrite

I am writing a program in Java where the output is written to a .txt file. Each time I run the program the file is overwritten. I do not want to use the append switch and add data to the file.

I would like to have it so a new file, with the same name, is created each time I run the program. For example, if `overflow.txt` is the file name, and I run the program three times, the files `overflow(1).txt`, `overflow(2).txt`, and `overflow(3).txt` should be made.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: overflow(1).txt is not the same file as overflow(2).txt; they have different names.

Answer (score 3):

Check if the file exists, if so rename it. Using `File.exists` and `FileUtils.moveFile`

You would need to do this recursively until no conflict is found.

Answer (score 3):

Check if the file exists first. If so, modify the name.

```
String origName = "overflow";
String ext = ".txt";
int num = 1;
file = new File(origName + ext);
while (file.exists()) {
 num++;
 file = new File(myOrigFileName +"(" + num + ")" + ext);
}
```

Modify depending on actual requirements. Question is not very clear.

Answer (score 2):

"A new file with the same name" doesn't make sense in most file systems.

In your example, you've got three files with *different* names:

- overflow(1).txt
- overflow(2).txt
- overflow(3).txt

The bit in brackets is still part of the name. If you want to emulate that behaviour, you'll have to:

- Detect the presence of the "plain" filename (if you want to write to that if it doesn't exist)
- Start counting at 1, and work out the "new" filename each time by removing the extension, adding the count in brackets, then putting the extension back
- Keep counting until you find a filename which doesn't exist

Comment: I think he is wanting a roll-over where overflow.txt is created the first time then renamed to overflow(2).txt when the app is run the next time. Sounds like a log4j file rolling system.

Comment: @JonSkeet I apologize, and you are correct. What I listed are three different files. But is it possible to have multiple files with the same name but different data?

Comment: @Paul: No. At least, not in most file systems. How would you tell them apart, if not by name?

Answer (score 1):

```
String dirPath = "./";
String fileName = dirPath + "overflow.txt";
if(new File(dirPath + fileName).exist())
{
    int counter = 0;
    while(new File(dirPath + "overflow(" + ++counter + ").txt").exist());
    fileName = "overflow(" + counter + ").txt";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you instanciate the File object, verify if it exists, if it does, just rename it by adding the braces and number, and check again.

Comment: There would need to be a recursive method to ensure that the rename doesn't conflict.

Comment: yep, thats why i said check again xD