# How to create multiple java txt files without overriding the previous data?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing to a file without overwriting or appending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055695/writing-to-a-file-without-overwriting-or-appending)

Hi I am creating a program that executes data and prints into a txt file.  The problem I am having is every time I run the program is overrides my previous txt file. I do not want it to override nor do I want to append the data.  I would like to create a new txt file each time having it produce a date or time it was created.  Could someone assist me please?

Here is my code:

```
private static PrintWriter outFile;
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    //Main Method
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {



         //creates the new file to be saved
        outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("trilogy.txt"));
        //Create a generator object to create random numbers
         Random gen = new Random ();

        //Create a scanner object to scan user input.
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

         DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
         //get current date time with Date()
         Date date = new Date();
         outFile.println(dateFormat.format(date));
         outFile.println();

        //Prompts the user to input how many lock combinations he/she wants generated.
         System.out.print ("Enter quantity: "); 
         int quantity = scan.nextInt();


        int count = 1;
        //Loop - Only numbers 1 - 5 are used
        //       Only five numbers are generated per one lock combination 
         for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
         {

                int n1 = gen.nextInt(5)+1;
                int n2 = gen.nextInt(5)+1;
                int n3 = gen.nextInt(5)+1;
                int n4 = gen.nextInt(5)+1;
                int n5 = gen.nextInt(5)+1;


    //While loop making sure that NO numbers are repeated
        while (n2==n1)
         {
            n2 = gen.nextInt(5)+1;
         }

               while (n3==n2 || n3 == n1 || n3==n4||n3==n5)
               {
                   n3 = gen.nextInt(5)+1;
               }

                    while (n4 == n3 || n4 == n2 || n4 == n1||n4==n5)
                    {
                        n4 = gen.nextInt(5)+1;
                    }

                        while (n5== n1 || n5==n2 || n5==n3 || n5==n4)
                        {
                            n5 = gen.nextInt(5)+1;
                        }

            //If statements that output the random lock combinations in different formats.
                        if (n1==1){
                            outFile.println ("(" + count +") "  +   (n1*10 +n2) +"-"+ (n3*10+n4)+"-"+n5);}
                        else if (n2==2){
                            outFile.println ("(" + count +") "  +   n2 + "-" + (n1*10 + n3)+ "-" + (n4*10+ n5));}
                        else if (n3==3){
                            outFile.println ("(" + count +") "  +   (n3*10 +n2) +"-"+ n1+ "-" +(n4*10+n5));}
                        else if (n4 == 4){
                            outFile.println ("(" + count +") "  +   (n4 +"-"+ (n2*100 +n3*10+n1)+"-"+n5));}
                        else
                            outFile.println ("(" + count +") "  +   (n5) +"-"+ (n2) +"-"+ (n3) + "-"+ (n4) +"-" +(n1));

                        count++;

            //Spaces one line in between each lock combination
            outFile.println();

         }
         outFile.close();
        }

}
```

Comment: Odd that this question was asked less than an hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055695/writing-to-a-file-without-overwriting-or-appending

Comment: It is a duplicate, but I prefer this version to the original

Answer (score 1):

Try change this:

```
        outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("trilogy.txt"));
```

for this to append the text:

```
        outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("trilogy.txt",true));
```

:)

Comment: From API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

FileWriter(File file, boolean append)
          Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.

Comment: Moral of the story: always, ALWAYS read methods' specs

Comment: HI Angel Olle Blazquez thanks for the feed back.  I trying to avoid it appending and outputting at the end of the file.  I would like for it to create a new txt file each time the user runs the program instead of overriding.

Comment: Try this:

`outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("trilogy"+new Date()+".txt"));`

and comment

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following line:

```
 outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("trilogy.txt"));
```

to something that has the time/date on it:

```
 outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("trilogy" + DATE_TIME + ".txt"));
```